# Does $\mathbf{n}\otimes \mathbf{m}=\mathbf{m}\otimes \mathbf{n}$ in the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products, young-tableaux

Consider the two irreducible representations, $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{m}$, of $su_\Bbb{C}(N)$. The tensor product $\mathbf{n}\otimes \mathbf{m}$ can be found using Young tableaux as follows:

1. Write $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{m}$ as Young tables and fill the second one (i.e. $\mathbf{m}$) with the letters $a$ in the first row, $b$ in the second and so on.
2. Attach boxes from $\mathbf{m}$ to $\mathbf{n}$ such that:

   1. We have a Young tabulaux
   2. When reading the numbers from right to left and top to bottom the number of $a$s must exceed or be equal to the number of $b$s which must exceed or equal the number of $c$s etc. (i.e. a lattice permutation).

My question is: Instead of filling the boxes of $\mathbf{m}$ with letters and adding them to $\mathbf{n}$ can we fill the boxes of $\mathbf{n}$ with letters and add them to $\mathbf{m}$? i.e. in the context of Clebsch-Gordan decompositions does $\mathbf{n}\otimes \mathbf{m}=\mathbf{m}\otimes \mathbf{n}$

Comment: Yes. If $U$ and $V$ are any finite dimensional $\mathfrak{su}_N$-modules, there is a well-defined linear transformation $\phi:U\otimes V\to V\otimes$ such that $\phi(u\otimes v)=v\otimes u$ for all vectors $u\in U, v\in V$. Scores of details to check there, but it is an exercise in basic properties of tensor products. It is then very easy to check that A) $\phi$ is a homomorphism of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$-modules, B) its own inverse, and therefore an isomorphism of representations.

Comment: Yes, but this is not immediately obvious (when considered in the combinatorial setting). It is completely trivial that the tensor product is symmetric though, so there is the proof (except that what you describe is not quite correct, as that really describes the rule for $gl(N)$).

Comment: (cont'd) Because all the f.d. representations can be decomposed in an essentially unique way into a direct sum of irreducibles, the multiplicities you get in Clebsch-Gordan for the two tensor product are necessarily all equal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ye sorry when I said $su(N)$ I implicitly meant $su_\Bbb{C}(N)$, which I think these rules do apply to.

Comment: No, they really don't, because you get partitions of longer length than those that describe modules for the Lie algebra. Whenever you get something in this extra row in your tableau, you need to remove that number of boxes from all rows to get the correct partition to label your irreducible.

Comment: To see this, just take the smallest possible example, with rank $1$ and the partitions being just the number $1$ each, giving with this rule the partitions $(1,1)$ and $(2)$, but the first one does not correspond to an irreducible and should be replaced by a $0$ which is indeed the highest weight of an irreducible in that tensor product.